# Wait for async function to return a value in Typescript.

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, promise, wait

I have a function (Function1) that calls another function (Function2) that returns a string.

I want Function1 to call Function2, but wait and get the return value of Function2. How do you go about doing that? Here's my code (which does not work as intended):

Here is my Function1:

```
async Function1() {
    const message = await this.dialogButtonPress();
    alert(message);
}
```

Here is my Function2:

```
async dialogButtonPress() : Promise<string> {
    const doneButtonPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const doneButton = document.getElementById("done-button");
        const resolver = () => {
            resolve();
            doneButton.removeEventListener("click", resolver);
        }
        doneButton.addEventListener("click", resolver);
    });

    const cancelButtonPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        const cancelButton = document.getElementById("cancel-button");
        const resolver = () => {
            resolve();
            cancelButton.removeEventListener("click", resolver);
        }
        cancelButton.addEventListener("click", resolver);
    })

    doneButtonPromise.then(() => {
        console.log("DONE BUTTON PRESSED!");
        return "Confirm";

    });

    cancelButtonPromise.then(() => {
        console.log("CANCEL BUTTON PRESSED!");
        return "Cancel";
    });      
}
```

Comment: For starters `dialogButtonPress` doesnt return anything (there is no return statement).

Comment: You need to return something (promise) from the second function. Not sure what exactly do you want as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `Promise.race` as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46962721/1906307) suggests, you won't be cleaning up the event handler for the button that was *not* pressed. You'll be cleaning up only the handler for the button that *was* pressed. If it were me, I'd just combine the event handlers to ensure that everything is cleaned up when any button is pressed:

```
async dialogButtonPress(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        const doneButton = document.getElementById("done-button")!;
        const cancelButton = document.getElementById("cancel-button")!;
        const resolver = (ev: Event) => {
            doneButton.removeEventListener("click", resolver);
            cancelButton.removeEventListener("click", resolver);
            // This is where we determine which button was clicked.
            resolve(ev.target === doneButton ? "Confirm" : "Cancel");
        }
        doneButton.addEventListener("click", resolver);
        cancelButton.addEventListener("click", resolver);
    });
}
```

And it could scale to any number of buttons:

```
async dialogButtonPress(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        // You just need to expand this map in order to support additional buttons.
        const idToResponse: Record<string, string> = {
            "done-button": "Confirm",
            "cancel-button": "Cancel",
        };
        const buttons = Object.keys(idToResponse).map((id) => document.getElementById(id)!);
        const resolver = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
            for (const button of buttons) {
                button.removeEventListener("click", resolver);                    
            }
            // We index into idToResponse to convert the button's id to a specific response.
            resolve(idToResponse[(ev.target as Element).id]);
        }

        for (const button of buttons) {
            button.addEventListener("click", resolver);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your solution (the first one) always returns "Cancel" even if I press the Confirm button.

Comment: @Roka545 The general principle is sound, and it works fine when I try it in the TypeScript playground with simple HTML. However, it is possible to write HTML that complicates things. And you have to make sure that you don't have a typo anywhere. I don't know why it would not work for you since I don't see your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
doneButtonPromise.then(() => {
    console.log("DONE BUTTON PRESSED!");
    return "Confirm";

});

cancelButtonPromise.then(() => {
    console.log("CANCEL BUTTON PRESSED!");
    return "Cancel";
});
```

To

```
return Promise.race([
    doneButtonPromise.then(() => {
        console.log("DONE BUTTON PRESSED!");
        return "Confirm";
    }),
    cancelButtonPromise.then(() => {
        console.log("CANCEL BUTTON PRESSED!");
        return "Cancel";
    })
]);
```